# Apply "onclick" to all elements in an iFrame

Tags: iframe, onclick

How do I use the JavaScript DOM to apply `onclick` events to links inside of an `iframe`?

Here's what I'm trying that isn't working:

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('a').onclick = function();
```

No errors seem to be thrown, and I have complete control of the stuff in the `iframe`.

Here is some code to test and see if I can at least count how many `div`'s are in my `iframe`.

```
// access body
var docBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

// create and load iframe element
var embed_results = document.createElement('iframe');
embed_results.id = "myIframe";
embed_results.setAttribute("src", "http://www.mysite.com/syndication/php/embed.php");

// append to body
docBody.appendChild(embed_results);

// count the divs in iframe and alert   
alert(document.getElementById("myIframe").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('div').length);
```

Comment: Can you modify the iframe's page content?

Comment: Could you provide some more code, so that we can look for errors? I'd like to see the context in which this code is fired. Check if this code is run after the frame's content is loaded, not earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible for an iFrame to source content from another website on a different domain.

Being able to access content on other domains would represent a security vulnerability to the user and so it is not possible to do this via Javascript.

For this reason, you can not attach events in your page to content within an iFrame.

Comment: It is possible if you control the iframe on both domains - http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 3):

getElementsByTagName returns a NodeCollection, so you have to iterate throgh this collection and add onclick handler to every node in that collection. The code below should work.

```
var links = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<links.length;++i)links[i].onclick=function(){}
```

also make sure, you run this code after the frames' content is loaded

```
embed_results.onload=function(){
   // your code
}
```

Comment: As Jon already answered, JavaScript security policy doesn't allow the browser to access or modify page contents from other domain.