# Update iframe src

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I've got a simple chrome extension that is linked with an iframe. The src points to a domain with various sub pages. When a user clicks off the iframe and the panel disappears. The src is forgotten and once reactivated it reloads the original src instead of the page the user last left off. Is it possible to save the iframes src and update for the user via javascript?

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action":{
"default_icon":"icon.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html",
"default_title": "Test"
}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
<body style="padding:0; margin:0;"><iframe style="padding:0; margin:0;" width="315"height="306" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could try `localStorage` to store the src.

Comment: YDid that actually work for you? I tried it from the source : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3714005/2762516   but didn'twork. Only returns already set url property, but not newly navigated url from the users actions?

Comment: I'm looking into the localStorage right now.

Comment: The local storage wont be an issue. It saves anything you cram in it. I just couldn't get this line of code, to actually return what the current url state of the iframe was, not the initial property of it set during run time. So curious myself. That way I can also use the method.  :)

Comment: Yeah it would be great, i've tried various solutions but no luck yet. :D

Comment: Will the user be navigating within your domain, or outside of it? If outside, from what I know, you cannot track it. You can find a refernce here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903661/how-to-track-the-user-in-an-iframe   Good luck!

Comment: Nope the user will stay on my domain. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've been using var currentFrame = document.getElementById("kml_frame").src; to fetch the current url but it returns the original src and not the actual content url. is there another way?