# Call a function in javascript on all onclick events

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function in javascript. I want to call this function on click of every events or at least on click of all the onclick events in the document.

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: try to type this question in the search bar you have a few millions duplicate in here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878445/get-all-elements-with-onclick-in-them/2878503#2878503 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753863/apply-onclick-to-all-elements-in-an-iframe/753939#753939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        <!--

        document.onclick = myClickHandler;


        function myClickHandler() {
          alert("The document was clicked!");
        }
        -->
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
         click anywhere within this document.
         <a href="x.html">this will fire the handler too!</a>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Question was about calling a function on all existing onclick events, not to create a new onclick event...

Comment: Read your comment, digest it - and then realise that both are the same... unless he's trying to create polymorphic javascript, then the fact that it's a new handler doesn't matter.